# How to monitor file downloads from browser using python

Tags: python, download, operating-system, interrupt, monitor

I have a requirement in which I want to monitor if any file is being downloaded using a browser. I want to write an executable using python. If a file is attempted to download, my goal is to interrupt the download to file system and send it to a server (On LAN) for analysis before being downloaded to the end user.

I am not sure how to achieve the above goal and what level of control I need on OS level to do so. Any help regarding this matter would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad but generally speaking you can't intercept https traffic without having the user to trust your root certificate (and running a mitm proxy). You _can_ write a browser extension but again the user has to load it. It all depends on how much control you have on the user's computer and configuration.

Comment: I can run an executable on the user's computer so I have the control. I was thinking to write the script in python then convert it to an executable. I am not looking to intercept traffic either, just manipulate file downloads like antiviruses do.

Comment: Antiviruses usually install their own https inspection certificate. In order to detect a file "download", you must intercept network traffic. If you are simply interested in any newly created/modified files, your task might be easier, but in that case you don't have a distinction between downloaded and user created files.

Comment: Yes, for the sake of logic I have implemented the file system monitoring approach.  But it does not differentiate between downloaded files and manually created ones. Moreover, it limits me to monitoring a specific directory for downloads, if user selects a custom location, the approach fails. So what approach do you think I should take, in order to achieve this? Should I create a self-signed certificate for this and inspect traffic using a packet sniffer maybe? I realize I am asking very generic questions. But I have found little help from my supervisors. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: This is not a trivial problem to solve. Yes, you should create a self-signed root certificate, then spoof every server certificate with a similar but new (signed with your CA) certificate. A packet sniffer is not sufficient to implement this as you can't easily rewrite the spoofed http/s traffic. You might consider purchasing an Internet gateway (or an open source tool such as pfsense) and force users to access the Internet through the gateway. This approach has limitations too, but much easier and robust than running something on the client itself.